# Error in ionic 2 build or run

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to run below command but gives me typescript module error like below:

> ```
> ionic cordova run android
> Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
> ```

Please help me to get rid of this!

Below is my inoic info output:

```
ionic info
```

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI    : CLI version 1.2.2 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.4.0
npm               : 5.2.0 
OS                : Linux 3.13
```

Below is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "checkCookieApp: An Ionic project"
}
```

This is my package.json file using which I am running `npm install`

Comment: Obvious basic question..are you running this command in your ionic project?

Comment: Yes. in ionic folder itself

Comment: ok.. can you add your package.json to the question?

Comment: @Suraj, Added package.json code

Comment: @RahulMankar check the last but one comment in this link and see if it helps - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-error-cannot-find-module-typescript-on-windows/100276/12

Comment: Thanks Gandhi! I gone through this also. I run npm install, deleted node_modules but was not working. I run installing app-scripts too. Finally by running below answer added by me works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got solved by installing typing-script \n "

> npm install -g tsd

And creating new ionic 2 project and running below -

> ionic cordova run android

Works for me on same node 8.4.0 version.